# Loading guest OS's (Windows) localhost through my host's (Mountain Lion) browsers

Tags: windows-7, networking, macos, visual-studio, vmware-fusion

For work I have to develop in Visual Studio, which I run via VMware's fusion 5.

I *really* want to test via my mac's native browsers for a multitude of reasons.  that is, view the IIs web stuffs that my windows VM should expose, in my mac's own native Firefox, Chrome... etc.  if I could expose a pretty URL, that would be even better, but I would certainly settle for an ugly IP :)

I got a decent number of views but no response when [I asked](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/414456) in VMware's own boards.

Everyone seems to want to go the other direction (developing in sublimetext/textmate serving up through MAMP and exposing it to windows browsers to test) and there seems to be tried a true solutions for this.  unfortunately (or fortunately depending on your preference) my startup is pretty entrenched in the visual studio development tools.

I'm really hoping that someone knows the answer to this.

Comment: (I guess that although you write 'guest OS's *localhost*' you don't mean 127.0,0.1 but the Windows NAT'd 172.16.54.x address.) "Sharing my Mac's network connection (NAT)" is definitely the setting you want, so you are on the right path. Turn off the firewall on your Mac too, not only on Windows, just in case. Can you ping the Windows guest at all? Can you access some other port, let's say 135 or 445 (open Terminal on ML and type: 'telnet 172.16.54.x 135' or 'telnet 172.16.54.x 445')?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: How did you arrange networking to the windows part? Bridged? NATted? Asking because it will result in different answers.